# InnoSetup - how to ask user to type license key or product key and match that code with compiled constant?

Tags: windows, security, windows-8, installation, inno-setup

I have to distribute a setup.exe made using innoSetup, where per user and per PC it has to be licensed.

I was thinking to give them a license key/product key like Windows 8.1 which they have to type in the InnoSetup. and match it with embedded constant or live over internet. Once the validation is done then the setup.exe will be complete else it wont install.

Is there any sample for such with innosetup, how can i do that please?

Comment: That would require build for each installation separately (unless you'd find a way to modify the output binary). Also, having a constant serial number stored in a setup is not secure.

Comment: @TLama: i want to embed the product/license key as compiled per user/per pc and when they want to install setup.exe it will live connect with our `https://server.com/validation.php?innosetupcode=blablabla` once i give them valid return certificate or file or another code then it should be treated as SUCCESS to move next. At-least by this way i can not make 100% but 50% safe for my case. How can we do this with InnoSetup please?

Comment: Note that this should also be checked in you application. It's trivial to extract the files from the setup bypassing the installer checks, or to copy them from a machine once installed.

Comment: @YumYumYum this code only prevents your user from using the installer. Once installed a user can simply copy/paste the install directory to another user or a zip on a torrent site...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create a page for entering serial numbers you can enable the [`UserInfoPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_userinfopage) directive and write a handler for the [`CheckSerial`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CheckSerial) event:

```
#define SerialNumber "123456"

[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
UserInfoPage=yes
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
function CheckSerial(Serial: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Serial = '{#SerialNumber}';
end;
```

INVALID Serial:
[image]

VALID Serial:
[image]

I have used a preprocessor defined constant because that allows you to simplify the build process. You can then define such constant from outside the script, with [`extended command line compiler`](http://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_isppcc.htm) and make e.g. a batch script that will build the setup with a defined serial number.

You would just **remove the first (hardcoded) line** from the above script and run a command line like this (for serial number `654321`):

```
iscc "/dSerialNumber=654321" "C:\Script.iss"
```

Of course in real you will need to take care about administration of the output setup files and their serial numbers but the system that you choose is upon you. [`Command line compiler`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=compilercmdline) allows you to specify the output path and a file name which is more than enough to build such system.

Comment: So, we should build a different setup for each user I guess, if we want to have different keys for each user. But is this approach safe?

Comment: It is usually better to only validate that the serial number has a correct checksum in the setup - and let the application deal with the verification of the serial number - instead of building a different setup for each user that actually contains the serial number.